# select with several joins on the same table

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I got a problem doing this job :

I have this table (Items) :

```
ItemId   Name  
1        Test  
2        Foo  
3        Bar  
4        Etc
5        Some
```

Every single item has several commands linked to it, in a table CommandItem :

```
CommandId   ItemId  
912         2
916         2
922         2
954         2
976         3
977         3
979         3
982         3
998         4
1001        4
1020        4
1035        4
1039        5
1041        5
```

I want to get only a few sorts of commandId, that matches "functions" stored in a table Command :

```
CommandId   FunctionId
912         81
916         72
922         56
954         13
976         81
977         72
979         56
982         13
998         81
1001        72
1020        56
1035        13
1039        81
1041        72
```

I only want commandId with FunctionId 81, 72 or 56.
Let's say their names are :
 81 : yellow
 72 : Brown
 56 : black

EDIT : in some cases, some commands may not exist for an itemId.
For example, we could say that itemId 5 has a command for yellow and Brown, but not for black.
In that case, I still need itemId 5 to appear in the table, with "NULL" for black.

The final view I want has this form :

```
 ItemId      Name   Yellow  Brown  Black
 1           Test   NULL    NULL   NULL
 2           Foo    912     916    922
 3           Bar    976     977    979
 4           Etc    998     1001   1020
 5           Some   1039    1041   NULL
```

I tried to make this :

```
select 
    i.itemid, 
    i.name,
    c1.CommandId as brown, 
    c2.CommandId as yellow,
    c3.CommandId as black
from item i
inner join commanditem ci 
    on i.itemid = ci.itemid 
inner join command c1 
    on ci.CommandId = c1.CommandId and c1.FonctionId = 81
left outer  join command c2 
    on ci.CommandId = c2.CommandId and c2.FonctionId = 72
left outer  join command c3
    on ci.CommandId = c3.commandId and c3.FonctionId = 56
```

I also tried with inner joins, with pivot... but without success.

I hope I am clear enough, thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
select
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    c1.CommandId as brown,
    c2.CommandId as yellow,
    c3.CommandId as black
from (items i left outer join (commanditem ci1 inner join command c1 on ci1.commandid = c1.commandid) on i.itemid = ci1.itemid
              left outer join (commanditem ci2 inner join command c2 on ci2.commandid = c2.commandid) on i.itemid = ci2.itemid
              left outer join (commanditem ci3 inner join command c3 on ci3.commandid = c3.commandid) on i.itemid = ci3.itemid)
where
      (c1.functionid = 81 or c1.functionid is null)
  and (c2.functionid = 72 or c2.functionid is null)
  and (c3.functionid = 56 or c3.functionid is null)
```

I tested it on another DBMS, but as it is standard SQL, it might work for you too.
The result was:

```
┌─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│itemid       │name      │brown        │yellow       │black        │
├─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│            2│Foo       │          912│          916│          922│
│            3│Bar       │          976│          977│          979│
│            4│Etc       │          998│         1001│         1020│
│            1│Test      │             │             │             │
└─────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
(4 rows)
```

OK, I see. The next query seems to do the right thing:

```
select
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    c1.CommandId as brown,
    c2.CommandId as yellow,
    c3.CommandId as black
from (items i left outer join (commanditem ci1 inner join command c1 on ci1.commandid = c1.commandid and c1.functionid = 81) on i.itemid = ci1.itemid
              left outer join (commanditem ci2 inner join command c2 on ci2.commandid = c2.commandid and c2.functionid = 72) on i.itemid = ci2.itemid
              left outer join (commanditem ci3 inner join command c3 on ci3.commandid = c3.commandid and c3.functionid = 56) on i.itemid = ci3.itemid)
```

with the new data, it produces the desired result:

```
┌─────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│itemid       │name      │brown        │yellow       │black        │
├─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│            1│Test      │             │             │             │
│            2│Foo       │          912│          916│          922│
│            3│Bar       │          976│          977│          979│
│            4│Etc       │          998│         1001│         1020│
│            5│Some      │         1039│         1041│             │
└─────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Hi, this works great but it shows only rows where every functions exists. why does it do that as you've used outer joins ?

Comment: I actually forgot to say that some commands may not exist for specific item, like for example only Brown and yellow for itemid 2. I will edit that

Comment: @Aeron I corrected the query, but left the original query in my answer. It'll be a good exercise to try to understand why the original query doesn't work (in the general case).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. i just dont get how I couldn't find the answer :(

Comment: yeah I assume every single command has to exist in the first query, otherwise it won't appear. but I'm not good enough to get why !

Comment: Well, it's quite simple actually. In the first query a valid combination of commanditem and command but with the wrong functionid can occur. This is then filtered out by the where clause. In the second query only combinations with a valid functionid are regarded.
I admit it's all a bit tricky. And believe me, I'm not a huge fan of outer joins, at least not of more than one outer join. They tend to make queries very hard to understand.

Comment: Yes that may be hard to read that. I hope this query will do the job when managing huge volumes of commands. I always expect queries with high number of joins to perform badly over big volumes of data. Thanks again @Ronald

Comment: If you want to run this query with huge data volumes, you probably run into performance problems. Transposing tables (which is effectively what you do) is not the strength of SQL. The better approach would be to join the 3 tables using an inner join (missing rows are easily handled by the program; no need to artificially enlarge the output) and have a program fill in the matrix. That would be very fast, easy to implement and maintain, and flexible (just imagine the query if you want to have 5 functionids).